# HTTPS Everywhere Exclusion when blocking all unencrypted requests

Tags: google-chrome, https-everywhere

I am using HTTPS Everywhere in Chrome to only allow encrypted browsing. However, I have some sites that run on the local intranet which are not capable of doing https. Is it possible to add exclusions or a whitelist manually while using the "block all unencrypted requests" option in HTTPS Everywhere?

I see on the EFF website that it is possible to create an exclusion to a ruleset which will allow an unsecure connection. However, when using the option "block all unencrypted requests", there is no ruleset, so I don't know what I would add the exclusion to.

I would prefer not to disable "block all unecrypted requests".

Comment: You do understand you can make intranet connections with minimal work right?

Comment: That's unlikely as I have no control over these intranet sites.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked a long time ago, so it is possible that EFF has changed things since. The solution is quite simple, fortunately.

To exclude a website, navigate to the site in question, (it doesn't matter if this results in an error, you just want the URL to be up in your URL bar) and then click on the HTTPS Everywhere extension widget. If it's hidden, make sure you have it up in your toolbar before following these steps. From there, you can just hit the big button that says "Disable on this site".

A few more options are shown when clicking on the "See more" dropdown, although the steps described above should fix your issue. Also make sure that your browser in question is not blocking HTTP for your website, either.